# fsck wont fix efs partitions

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, fsck

I have some efs drives that I am attempting to repair the file-systems of. 
when I run fsck, it returns with an error essentially saying  the device isn’t e2fsck. I looked in synaptic for efs support, but I couldn’t find anything.

here is an article about efs:
http://www.linux.org/threads/extent-file-system-efs.4447/

What commands can i use to repair an EFS partition?

```
# fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: What is an efs drive? The fsck is only for ext2, ext3, ext4 family of formats. You have to then use different tools for other formats.

Comment: efs is a filesystem from the 1990's, for SGI drives, and fsck was formerly able to do the repairs.  maybe i need to go find old fsck source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux `fsck` utility is basically just a front-end for filesystem-specific filesystem check utilities such as `fsck.ext2` (aka `e2fsck`) and `fsck.xfs` (which actually does nothing; to check XFS, you must use `xfs_check`, and to repair it, you must use `xfs_repair`).

If you really mean EFS, then that's pretty exotic. I just checked the kernel configuration utility, and it reports:

> EFS is an older file system used for non-ISO9660 CD-ROMs and hard
>   disk partitions by SGI's IRIX operating system (IRIX 6.0 and newer
>   uses the XFS file system for hard disk partitions however).
>
> This implementation only offers read-only access

I found no matches to `EFS` in packages in Synaptic. Between the fact that EFS is an obscure read-only filesystem in Linux and the fact that there seems to be no package that might hold an `fsck.efs` utility, my guess is that either you're not remembering correctly that it used to be possible or you had an *extremely* rare and non-standard `fsck.efs` utility installed on a computer at some time. Of course, an old IRIX should be able to check the disk.

It's also possible that your disk isn't actually EFS, but the newer XFS. In this case, you'd need to install the `xfsprogs` utility to get the `xfs_check` and `xfs_repair` utilities.

More broadly, I have to question the need for an EFS check utility in an OS that provides read-only access to the filesystem. The only chance you'd have to write to such a filesystem would be in IRIX, and it should have a suitable check utility. Without the ability to write to the filesystem from Linux, in theory you shouldn't be able to damage it in Linux, except by blundering about with `dd` or something. If you're stuck with an old EFS disk, it's probably best to transfer its files to a more modern filesystem. If the point of the question is that you have such a disk and it won't mount, then perhaps you could use TestDisk to pull individual files off of it. That's likely to be a painful process, but short of dusting off an old IRIX system, it might be your best bet. Some further context about your problem might help us offer other solutions.